# Posting problems with dynamical form using jquery

Tags: forms, post, dynamic, toggle

I wrote a dynamic form using jQuery, basically like this:

```
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="radio" name="rgroup" value="1">small form
<input type="radio" name="rgroup" value="2">whole form
<input type="text" name="inp1">
<div id="formpart">
<input type="text name="inp2">
</div
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

And

```
$('input[type=radio][name=rgroup]').change(function(){
    $('#formpart').toggle();      
});
```

Visually everything works fine, but in my $_POST array, the input field inp2 does appear, but is always empty... What can I do about it?

Comment: Silly question: did you type something in the `inp2` field? Also, what happens if you create it a with defined `value`?

Comment: Yes, whatever I type into inp2, after posting $_POST['inp2']  is empty....

Comment: Just for testing purposes, can you post the data without any change to it (no listeners, no nothing)? Just do a `post` as it is (with `inp2` filled) and check `$_POST`.

Comment: Array( [inp1] => De waarde van input 1 [inp2] =>)

Comment: Is it missing a `"` in there? Should be `<input type="text" name="inp2">` (after `text`). Also, `</div` is missing `>`. Let's just make sure these are not the cause of our problems.

Comment: It is not the exact code, because it is a huge form. The toggle seems to be the problem, or couldn't that be it?